# Parsing invalid integers as null within orderby

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

```
var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };
list = list.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Can anybody advise how to amend the above code so that a null value is returned for every value that fails to parse as an integer?

I think I need to replace `Parse` with `TryParse` somehow?

**Clarification**:

The program accepts 3 integers from 3 different textboxes, sorts them and inserts the sequence into a database. If a non-integer is entered, I wanted to treat it as a null value.

For example, if `TextBox1.Text = ""`, `TextBox2.Text = "45"` and `TextBox3.Text = "8"`, the sequence inserted would be: `0,8,45`.

However, I now think it might be better to exclude non-integers from the sort so for the same example, the resulting sequence would be something like: `8,45,N/A`.

Apologies for not being able to explain my requirements clearly.

Comment: This code would crash your application if you attempted to read a non-integer.

Comment: Given the confusion around the requirements (see my edited answer) it would *really* help if you'd clarify the question, ideally with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* you're really using LINQ to Objects, I'd write a separate method:

```
public static int? ParseOrNull(string text)
{
    int result;
    return int.TryParse(text, out result) ? (int?) result : null;
}
```

Then:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => ParseOrNull(x)).ToArray();
```

This will cope with text values which are either genuine string references to non-numbers, or null references. You might want to overload `ParseOrNull` to accept an `IFormatProvider`.

This is just *ordering* by a nullable int, however. If you want values which invalid *replaced* with null, but other values to remain as strings (ordered by the numeric value) I suspect you want something more like:

```
var result = list.Select(x => new { Text = x, Numeric = ParseOrNull(x) })
                 .OrderBy(pair => pair.Numeric)
                 .Select(pair => pair.Numeric.HasValue ? pair.Text : null)
                 .ToArray();
```

If neither of these does what you want, please clarify your requirements.

Note that none of this will work with something like LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework, which wouldn't be able to translate your method into SQL.

Comment: Can I ask why the method is static?

Comment: Thanks Jon. Are you hinting that I shouldn't be using LINQ here?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: Why wouldn't it be? It doesn't depend on the state of any class.

Comment: @user1405195: Nope, using LINQ is fine - I was just wondering whether your real use case was against SQL. (Sometimes users ask questions using collections to simplify the question, but then complain that the answer doesn't work with LINQ to SQL.)

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused by the requirements, but this does not fulfill "so that a null value is returned for every value that fails to parse as an integer". It just "orders by null" for those values.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: See my edited version - and I agree, the requirements are very badly written.

Comment: Yep - this is pretty much my real use case and your solution works great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };
list = list.OrderBy(x =>
            {
                int val;
                return int.TryParse(x, out val) ? (int?)val : null;
            }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice use of a mutated local *inside the lambda*. Many people try to do this outside the lambda, which doesn't work right.

Comment: @EricLippert Do you mean closure on local `val`?

Comment: Yes. See http://ericlippert.com/2012/08/14/out-parameters-and-linq-do-not-mix/ for an example of doing it wrong.

Comment: @EricLippert Great! See my [profile on stackoverflow career](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/hamlethakobyan) at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the requirements and reading your code (which assigns the result to the same array), you still want *strings* as output, but ordered by their numeric value, and the strings that aren't parseable you want in the resulting array as `null`;

```
var result = 
    list
      .Select(x => { int tmp; return Int32.TryParse(x, out tmp) ? x : null; })
      .OrderBy(x => x);
```

Comment: That's not going to order by the numeric value though - it will put "12" ahead of "2". But +1 for getting to some of the differences in the question - see my edited answer for what I *think* is a valid result.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, yes, long work week apparently :) To fix it I'd pretty much have to go for your version with an anonymous type though, so leaving it as is.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    var list = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };
    list = list.OrderBy(x => ParseStringToInt(x)).ToArray();


    private int ParseStringToInt(string value)
    {
        int result;
        int.TryParse(value, out result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You're not handling the case when the parsing fails which the OP wants

Comment: Isn't that why there is a TryParse? and what value you can set in TextBox.Text to break my code?

Comment: The `TryParse` keeps a exception from occuring, but it doesn't let the OP identify the difference between "abc" from being entered into the textbox or "0"

Comment: But it DOES handles the exception, doesn't it. And no where in the OP it says that he needs to identify the exception. It says if there is an exception, then return null.

Comment: Yes and you are returning 0 and not null.